# How to delete a row table from Free Marker Template(FTL) using button ?, I am using Spring MVC+FTL

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have created a controller and a form and a FTL file for populating the table(table data I am taking from my model)
Is there any options to access our spring controller from FTL using button?